# How to use Field Calculator to calculate area as percentage?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I am searching for python code to use in Field Calculator to calculate area as a percentage in relation to another field?

[image]

The area percentage needs be calculated based on the total area for each "Basin_ID" separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

[Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with the statistics field of sum on Area_Ac and a case field of Basin_ID.

Then join the two tables together, and run Field Calculator like this:

Parser:

```
Python
```

Expression:

```
!Area_Ac!/!<sum field>!
```

Here is an ArcMap 10.1 script version:

```
import arcpy

vals = [[r for r in row] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["Basin_ID", "Area_Ac"])]
sums = dict([[i, float(sum(zip(*filter(lambda f: f[0] == i, vals))[1]))] 
            for i in sorted(list(set(zip(*vals)[0])))])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Basin_ID", "Area_Ac", "Area_perce"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:

        try:    row[2] = row[1]/sums.get(row[0])
        except:     pass

        rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest way I can think of without scripting.